# User level access control in Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, kibana, dashboard, search-guard

I need to create a dashboard for some reports and my first approach was ES/kibana but I need user based access to the dashboard and user should be able to see just his data, more like a token based access. I know using shield we can have index level access control and using nginx and lua we can have another level of role based access control. Is it possible to achieve user based access to data in ES/Kibana.

Also, Is there any other existing solutions which can be used for creating such kind of dashboard, open source preferably.

Please don't mark a duplicate of [How to set authentication in kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138936/how-to-set-authentication-in-kibana), its few months old query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SearchGuard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard)? I think it could fit your needs.
It's a free alternative to Shield (the comercial feature of Elastic). Shield would also fit your needs but is quite expensive, [although you get the development license.](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions/)

SearchGuard recently announced a version for elasticsearch 2.2 but still alpha. You also have versions for 1.x versions of elasticsearch.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).