# Authentication for Kibana server

Tags: security, authentication, elasticsearch, kibana

We are using Elasticsearch 2.3.4 and Kibana 4.5.3 in our application. We would like to add authentication to our Kibana server. That means, when running the kibana server from browser, it should prompt for user name and password.

We are looking open source software's/plugins to be added to Kibana and Elastic server.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: free (for basic features) and open source https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set authentication in kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138936/how-to-set-authentication-in-kibana)

Answer (score 0):

Kibana work really good with the plugin [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/kibana.html).

Answer (score 0):

shield plugin is not an open source project but instead you can use [searchguard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-kibana-plugin) or [elasticfence](https://github.com/elasticfence/kibana-auth-plugin).