# How to achieve authentication in kibana?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5, xpack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm new to ELK and want to perform authentication in kibana.

I have gone through the documents on LDAP and Native Realm.

Which will be the best one to do authentication.

Comment: authentication for end users ? Which version of Kibana you are using ?

Comment: Yes, for end users and kibana version is - 5.4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set authentication in kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138936/how-to-set-authentication-in-kibana)